# Resuming a Mass Effect completed game?

Tags: mass-effect

I just completed Mass Effect 1's main storyline and I'm a bit confused. I'm reading that upon completion of the game, levels 51-60 are unlocked. But I don't see a way for me to resume the character as opposed to starting over.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you start a new game, in addition to the Default and Custom Shepard options for your character, you should have the option to "Use Existing ID". This will allow you to begin a new game with your existing character (and continue to level up to level 60).

It's a "new game plus" bonus, so the additional levels are unlocked to allow for character build progress in a second playthrough.

Comment: Just please tell me I don't have to search the galaxy for the gases, metals, and ID tags again :/

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. Though you don't have to get everything, if you're not concerned about being a completionist on your second go around.

Comment: I don't need them for Mass Effect 2?

Comment: Hmm, that's a good point...I know that *some* items are taken into account in one way or another in the subsequent games, but I can't remember off-hand the details for each. You may want to search around the site to see if someone's asked about the various items before. If not, it's definitely good question material.

Comment: I'd additionally like to point out that it will likely take you ~3+ playthroughs to reach level 60 depending on the difficulty level and side missions done. It might be wise to consider playing a quick "hardcore playthrough"  and then concentrating on a completionist Insanity playthrough to prep your save for ME2.  Thems be the breaks...